# What is the idea behind private attribute access inside main? Java x C++

Tags: java, c++, encapsulation, program-entry-point

When using C++ one is not allowed to access a private attribute inside a main function. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test {
    private: int a;
    public:
       Test(int value) { a = value; }
       int getValue() { return a; }
};
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    Test test2(4);
    cout << test2.a; // Compile error! Test::a is private within this context
    cout << test2.getValue(); // OK!
    return 0;
}
```

It is clear why there is an error when accessing private attributes outside class methods, since C++ do not have main functions inside classes.

However, in Java it is allowed:

```
public class Test {
    private int a;
    public Test(int value) { a = value; }
    public int getValue() { return a; }
    public static void main (String args[]) { 
        Test test1 = new Test(4);
        System.out.println(test1.a);
    }
}
```

I understand in this case main is INSIDE the Test class. However, I cannot understand the idea WHY is this allowed, and what is the impact of this in the development/management of the code.

When learning C++, I once heard "Classes shouldn't have a main. Main acts with or uses instances of classes".

Can someone shed some light on this question?

Comment: `main` pretty much have to live within a class in java, since it would be illegal for it to live outside of a class. There is no global scope for functions in java.

Comment: I always just have the main entry point in a class with nothing else but the main function. It really doesn't make sense to have the main in a class to me either.

Comment: By the answers so far I believe this was a choice of the language developers: to not make exceptions to Main(), even if it was a special function, granting the access any other method would have.

Comment: It's not unusual to have multiple mains. For instance, it's often useful to have (non-production) code to open up each panel in a GUI application without having to go through the business of starting up the whole thing and clicking through to where the panel is shown with some relevant data.

Comment: You're also under no obligation to put `main()` functions in those of your classes that have private fields. Or to make classes with `main` functions capable of being instantiated. So there's no funny business with encapsulation or access going on here unless you want there to be. It's a minor quirk of the fact that Java's entry points happen to be static methods, and hence belong to a class, and hence can access that class's internals should you choose to give it any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at this from the wrong point of view. The question is not why *main* can acces the class internals. There is not *one* 'main' in Java. The important difference to this respect is that for C++ there is a single entry point into the application that is *main*, while in Java a single application can have multiple entry points, as many as one per class. The entry point must be a static method (member function in C++ jargon) of a class with a particular signature, and the behavior is exactly the same as for other static methods of the same class.

The reason that Java can have multiple entry points is that you tell the VM on startup where (what class) you want to start your application in. That is a feature that is not available in C++ (and many other languages)

Comment: Thanks. That's very interesting, I wasn't really looking at this point of view.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually do the same in C++:

```
class Test {
    private: int a;
    public:
       Test(int value) { a = value; }
       int getValue() { return a; }
       static void Main()
       {
          Test t(10);
          cout << t.a;
       }
};
```

It's as simple as that: in both languages, `private` variables are accessible only from inside the class.

> However, I cannot understand the idea WHY is this allowed.

It's just a language feature. If you weren't able to access privates from inside the class, what could you do with them?

Also, not that access-levels are class-wide, not instance-wide. That might be throwing you off. That means you can access a different instance's privates from an instance of the same class. Also, in C++, there's the `friend` keyword that gives you the same privileges.

Comment: Luchain, I understand this, but in this case this function Main inside the class is not a proper main(). It does not compile without ANOTHER main outside the class. Isn't correct? But in Java it compiles, runs, and everything is fine.

Comment: @MoacirPontiJr. yes. And? `main()` is just the entry point in C++, just as `MyClass::main()` is in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct. The second code is valid in Java because `main` is inside the `Test` class. To make it equivalent to the C++ code try to access the private member of a different class, which will fail to compile:

```
class Test2 {

    private int a;
    public Test(int value) { a = value; }
    public int getValue() { return a; }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main (String args[]) { 
        Test2 test2 = new Test2(4);
        System.out.println(test2.a); // does not compile
    }
}
```

The actual underlying difference is the fact that in C++ functions can exist outside classes, while in Java any method needs to be part of a class.

Answer (score 1):

`private` in Java could be considered "file local" c.f. package local. For example you can access private members of a class defined in the same outer class.

AFAIK, The assumption is you don't need to protect yourself from code in the same file.

```
public interface MyApp {
    class Runner {
        public static void main(String... args) {
            // access a private member of another class
            // in the same file, but not nested.
            SomeEnum.VALUE1.value = "Hello World"; 
            System.out.println(SomeEnum.VALUE1);
        }
    }

    enum SomeEnum {
        VALUE1("value1"),
        VALUE2("value2"),
        VALUE3("value3");
        private String value;

        SomeEnum(final String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/#!/2012/02/outer-class-local-access.html

Answer (score -2):

This reason is: `Java` is a fully `Object Oriented Programming` model, so in it any things must defined in class or smallest unit in java is class.

Comment: *fully Object Oriented Programming*... Don't get me started, the fact that you are *forced* to make everything a class does not mean that it is *fully* object oriented. Python is more object oriented than Java for what matters...

Comment: I don't compare Python with Java here.

Comment: my rant is about all the people that claim that java is 100% OO because it forces everything to be contained in a class, and that is false. I also (side not if you want) provided an example of a language that is more OO than java and has functions that are not members of classes, with the intention of making it more explicit that the two concepts are not really the same. Note that by providing a strictly more-OO example it can be inferred that Java cannot be 100% OO.

Comment: I don't compare Python with Java still, because I achieve several vote-down to our question about `Block Approch in Python and Java` ;) , your opinion is true but my opinion is : OOP must have a structure(such as real world), you can't define any behavior out of its container.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Define "fully Object Oriented Programming".  I've never seen two people define it identically.  **If** you take the definition as meaning that you have artificially forced all functions to be members of a class, whether they should be members (or even if the class should exist), then Java is fully OOP, and C++ isn't.  Of course, artificially forcing the superficial use of an inappropriate paradigm isn't exactly my idea of an advantage, but to each his own.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I am not even a fan of OO, and I was not the one to use *fully Object Oriented*, I just refuted on the fact that if there is something that is more OO then unless you believe in *fully* and *even fullier* the lesser one of the two cannot be *fully OO*. I can tell you that, for example, primitive types are not objects (nor behave like objects) in Java, which makes it a little less object oriented than other language where *all* types are objects. Forcing all functions to be in a class scope does not make up for this, for example.